# Mapreduce POJO mapping

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, mapping, pojo

i have a file in hdfs system which is the output of join of 3 tables related to sales data.
(sales header, item detail,tender detail).

The file will have columns from all the three tables combined.

If there are 3 items and 1 tender , i will have 6 rows for a transaction.
So there will be 6 lines in the file with same transaction number.
I can read this in mapper and create a DTO with all the fields

Now i want to construct the complex DTO structure out of this flattened DTO. 
Is there any pojo mapping framework available for this and will it support maping from a plain DTO to a complex structure.

Structure

```
public class PlainDTO{

String tranId;
String processDate;
String itemNumber;
String itemName;
int tenderId;
.......
......


}
```

From List, i need to convert to
below structure

```
public class ComplexDTO{

private SlsHeader slsHeader;
private Collection<SlsItems> items;
private Collection<SlsTender> tenderDetails

}
```

Comment: Also the final destination of this data is elastic search. I am planning to convert the complex dto to json in reducer. Is there any other good approach for  converting and loading data to ES from hadoop ?

Comment: You can use of Jackson library for this

Comment: With multiple lines per complex object, you might end up with 2 splits each containing a part of the complex object.

Answer (score 1):

Conversion from flat DTO to complex DTO is plain java stuff. Once you write it, and it stays like that. From complex DTO to json, you can use any JSON-Java parsers like Jackson or Gson.

The challenge could be, once you have this one-many mapping(DTO complex structure) in json, you should see how the Elastic search manages these relationships. I worked with Solr(similar to Elastic Search). They have child documents concept in Solr.

Also, at higher level, if your Elastic search client is java based, you can directly go from Flat structure to ES client, skipping json.